# Font not available in visual studio reporting services designer on windows 10

Tags: reporting-services, fonts, visual-studio-2015, windows-10

I'm using a barcode font ('Free 3 of 9 Extended', available [here](http://www.barcodesinc.com/free-barcode-font/)) in a rdlc report.

This is working fine in VS2012 and VS2015 on Windows 7 and 8, but after I upgraded to Windows 10, the font is no longer listed in the fonts dropdown list of the report designer (in VS2012 as well as VS2015).
Report elements that are using this font are displayed in the default font, both in the designer, and when running the report.

I do have a font called 'New' at the location where I would expect 'Free 3 of 9 Extended' in the font combobox of the designer of Visual Studio. But this font looks like the default font as well.

The font is still available in other programs like Word(pad) however.

screenshots: https://www.dropbox.com/s/vkrg363f1p88tk6/font%20bug%20rdlc%20on%20windows%2010.png?dl=0

Any ideas why this is happening and how it can be fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have still no idea why this happened, but I managed to fix it by opening the font with [FontForge](http://fontforge.github.io/en-US/) and saving it again as TTF.
I uninstalled the previous version in Windows and reinstalled the newly generated one, and it works now..

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me few days back. I tried uninstalling the font ("Myriad Pro Regular") from control panel and then installing it again (copy-paste will do for win-7). And then restarting the VS for a development machine and for server had to restart the RS services. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.
I already tried to close VS, uninstall and reinstall the font, and restart VS, but it didn't help unfortunately.
We're using local reports, so there's no report server involved..